# Same words from one table

Tags: mysql

I have a db table with stored interests of users:

```
CREATE TABLE `ade39_findme_settings_words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `word` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `clickeditem` (`user_id`),
  KEY `count` (`word`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Where word=interest

Now I want to search in this table for users having one or many same interests AND order this list by the amount of same interests. Any idea how the sql query would look like?

like search for "all users with similar(!) interest as user_id=62"

**Example:**

```
 USER  INTEREST
 62    riding
 62    reading
 62    dancing
 75    riding
 75    dancing
 80    riding
 81    rid
```

OUTPUT:

```
 USER  INTEREST   SAME_COUNT 
  75   riding     2
  80   riding     1
  81   rid        1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic behind the output `75   riding     2` but `80   riding     1`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I think because this is example for `USER 62` - `USER 75` has 2 common `INTEREST` (riding and dancing) with `USER 62` but `USER 80` has only one (riding). But why there is just `riding` in output it's a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Try This query.

```
SELECT user AS USER ,interest AS INTEREST,Count(*)AS SAME_COUNT 
FROM  ade39_findme_settings_words WHERE interest like '%rid%'
GROUP BY interest ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

its give you all interest which is having rid word in your case 75 and 80 users have two time but in my query group interest, output give 1 according to match interest keyword.
Hopefully this will complete your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to search in this table for users having one or many same
>   interests

This requirement is a little bit vague, but I created a sample query to get all the users who have the same interests as user 62 except himself:

```
mysql> SELECT user_id,word FROM ade39_findme_settings_words;
+---------+---------+
| user_id | word    |
+---------+---------+
|      62 | riding  |
|      62 | reading |
|      62 | dancing |
|      75 | riding  |
|      75 | dancing |
|      80 | riding  |
|      81 | rid     |
+---------+---------+

mysql> SELECT 
    word, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS users, 
    COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM
ade39_findme_settings_words
WHERE 
    user_id != 62 
AND word IN (
    SELECT word 
    FROM ade39_findme_settings_words
    WHERE user_id=62
)
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY cnt DESC;


+---------+-------+-----+
| word    | users | cnt |
+---------+-------+-----+
| riding  | 75,80 |   2 |
| dancing | 75    |   1 |
+---------+-------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The second query has a subquery, that returns all the interests of user 62.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2df4b/1)

Comment: It's a little strange but the author's output has also `81  rid  1`.

Comment: @user Yes, user 62 doesn't have it. I wish, he has formalized his requirements better.